# Chromakey glsl shader with transparent background

Tags: glsl, webgl, p5.js

This is an example of P5 js with chromakey shader (porting from shadertoy)
What is the best way to make the background image transparent? I tried to change it to a png image with transparency with loadImage() method and it didn't work, the sketch doesn't load. I even tried to enable the
gl.enable (gl.BLEND) in the setup function. Should I use the texture2d () method for background images as well, or do I just use color with alpha?

fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler2D tex1;
uniform vec2 iResolution;

mat4 RGBtoYUV = mat4(0.257,  0.439, -0.148, 0.0,
                        0.504, -0.368, -0.291, 0.0,
                        0.098, -0.071,  0.439, 0.0,
                        0.0625, 0.500,  0.500, 1.0 );

vec4 chromaKey = vec4(0.05, 0.63, 0.14, 1);

vec2 maskRange = vec2(0.005, 0.26);

float colorclose(vec3 yuv, vec3 keyYuv, vec2 tol)
{
    float tmp = sqrt(pow(keyYuv.g - yuv.g, 2.0) + pow(keyYuv.b - yuv.b, 2.0));
    if (tmp < tol.x)
        return 0.0;
    else if (tmp < tol.y)
        return (tmp - tol.x)/(tol.y - tol.x);
    else
        return 1.0;
}

void main()
{
    vec2 fragPos =  gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    vec4 texColor0 = texture2D(tex0, fragPos);
    vec4 texColor1 = texture2D(tex1, fragPos);

    vec4 keyYUV =  RGBtoYUV * chromaKey;
    vec4 yuv = RGBtoYUV * texColor0;

    float mask = 1.0 - colorclose(yuv.rgb, keyYUV.rgb, maskRange);
    gl_FragColor = max(texColor0 - mask * chromaKey, 0.0) + texColor1 * mask;
}
```

vertex shader:

```
attribute vec3 aPosition;

void main() {

  vec4 positionVec4 = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
  positionVec4.xy = positionVec4.xy * 2.0 - 1.0;

  gl_Position = positionVec4;
}
```

P5 js code snippet:

```
  function preload(){

     theShader = loadShader('webcam.vert', 'webcam.frag');

     img = loadImage('https://princetonlibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/p5js.png');
     //img = loadImage('https://p5js.org/assets/img/asterisk-01-01.png'); // use alpha

     //gl.enable(gl.BLEND);


  }
  function draw(){
     shaderTexture.shader(theShader);
     theShader.setUniform('tex0', cam);
     theShader.setUniform('tex1', img);
     theShader.setUniform('iResolution', [width, height]);
  }
```

[Complete code on glitch](https://glitch.com/~chromakey-shaderdoy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Setting dynamic chroma-key transparency

Add the following uniform to the frag shader

```
uniform float backgroundAlpha;
```

Change the last line of the frag shader from

```
gl_FragColor = max(texColor0 - mask * chromaKey, 0.0) + texColor1 * mask;
```

to

```
vec4 col = max(texColor0-mask*chromaKey,0.0) + texColor1*mask*vec4(vec3(1), backgroundAlpha);
if (col.a > 0.0) {
    gl_FragColor = col;
} else {
    discard;
}
```

Then set the uniform to the alpha level you want for the background

```
const bgLoc = gl.getUniformLocaton(program, "backgroundAlpha");
gl.uniform1f(bgLoc, 0);

// or with p5
theShader.setUniform('backgroundAlpha', 0);  // 0 is full transparent
```

Ensure that the blend mode is set

```
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

// however you do that in P5.js
```

**Important** Make sure you draw this object after any objects that are behind it. If you don't then the semi transparent edges will not show the background objects, only what is behind your object at the time of rendering.

**Note** that if you want it always to be fully transparent you don't need to add the second texture map, remove the `tex1` uniform and associated code in JS and frag shader. Then the last line is simply... (the uniform `backgroundAlpha` is not needed)

```
vec4 col = max(texColor0 - mask * chromaKey, 0.0);
if (col.a > 0.0) {
    gl_FragColor = col;
} else {
    discard;
}
```

### A better chromakey shader

The following shader removes the key color `keyRGBA` within the range 0 to `range.y` smoothing the transition with a (Hermite) curve for values `range.x` to `range.y`.

The color space conversion your code used looked very strange, I could not find anything that used that conversion. I used the color space YC<sub>b</sub>C<sub>r</sub> The luma `Y` is ignored so all that is needed are the  chrominance components

```
uniform sampler2D tex0;         
uniform vec4 keyRGBA;    // key color as rgba
uniform vec2 keyCC;      // the CC part of YCC color model of key color 
uniform vec2 range;      // the smoothstep range
uniform vec2 iResolution;

vec2 RGBToCC(vec4 rgba) {
    float Y = 0.299 * rgba.r + 0.587 * rgba.g + 0.114 * rgba.b;
    return vec2((rgba.b - Y) * 0.565, (rgba.r - Y) * 0.713);
}               
void main() {
    vec4 src1Color = texture2D(tex0,  gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution);
    vec2 CC = RGBToCC(src1Color);
    float mask = sqrt(pow(keyCC.x - CC.x, 2.0) + pow(keyCC.y - CC.y, 2.0));
    mask = smoothstep(range.x, range.y, mask);
    if (mask == 0.0) { discard; }
    else if (mask == 1.0) { gl_FragColor = src1Color; }
    else { gl_FragColor = max(src1Color - (1.0 - mask) * keyRGBA, 0.0); }
}
```

Set the uniforms `range`, `keyRGBA` and `keyCC` can be set as follows

```
const RGBAToCC = (r, g, b) => {
    const y = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b;
    return [(b - y) * 0.565, (r - y) * 0.713];
};
const keyRGBA = [0.05, 0.63, 0.14, 1];  // the green from your code
const range = [0.11, 0.22];             // A guess at the range needed
const keyCC = RGBAToCC(...keyRGBA);

theShader.setUniform('keyCC', keyCC);
theShader.setUniform('keyRGBA', keyRGBA);
theShader.setUniform('range', range);
```

**Note** that the alpha value of `keyRGBA` should be 1

Comment: Many thanks !
I want that greenscreen to be fully transparent. So I'm  using just the  tex0 receiving the webcam image. I enabled the blend modes and remove the img in p5 code , also I removed the tex1 in fragment shader. But its seem dosen't working. The greenscreen color still green.

I intend to create a scene like this [link] (http://www.quadrochave.com/Lab/webgl_shaders/glitch-chromakey.png)

Comment: @HenriqueBarone Chroma keying is very sensitive, when chroma keying a background most people will not notice the slight bleed of the key into the BG image but when alpha masking even a tiny bleed will show as non zero alpha. For the green in the image (linked in your comment) set `maskRange = vec2(0.11, 0.22)` as the range in your example is way too wide. You should make the mask range a `uniform` so that it can be tweaked as needed, no two greens are ever the same, especially from web cams

Comment: @Blindman67 thank you for the code , this works very well, if i would like to introduce spill removal in the same code could you please guide me what steps would i need to do.